# Pandas: 'Value set in a copy of slice from df' error when performing groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am working with a data frame:

```
mpl.head(1)
    cid     state   naics   year    log_diff_subsidies  log_diff_empcomp    log_diff_taxes  log_diff_rgdp   unemployment    party   date    bills   leg_totalbills  years_exp   prefix  disposition     catcode
0   N00003389   KY  518, 519    2013.0  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     8.1     Republican  2013    s1626-113   5   29  s   support     G5200

mpl_interest=mpl[['date', 'catcode', 'disposition', 'cid', 'bills']]

mpl_interest['billsum'] = mpl_interest.groupby(['date', 'catcode','disposition', 'cid'])['bills'].transform('nunique')
```

Here is where I get an error. I have performed this command before with similar dfs; occasionally I get this error, but it never seems to be a problem.

```
/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Does anyone know if I should be terribly worried about it? Is there a small syntax adjustment I can make to avoid it?

Comment: well it shouldn't raise the warning if you don't create the intermediate variable `mpl['billsum']=mpl[['date', 'catcode', 'disposition', 'cid', 'bills']].groupby(['date', 'catcode','disposition', 'cid'])['bills'].transform('nunique')`

Comment: Thank you EdChum! It's the little things that keep coming back get me.

Comment: Additionally if your intention is to operate on a copy then you can make it explicit here: `mpl_interest=mpl[['date', 'catcode', 'disposition', 'cid', 'bills']].copy()`